# can i reuse a model for training the network again with its values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i'm still new to the field of deep learning using keras and wanted to ask if it is possible to take a model after training the network and run the network again with the variables of that model?

in other words, say i train the network and reach an accuracy of 90%, can i train the network again starting with the variable values reached before in order to further improve the accuracy.and if so how can i do so in python?

i would appreciate if you can explain this to me or provide a resource for me to learn about something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This can be described as either transfer learning or fine tuning

If you have saved your model as a h5, you can load it with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

load_modelmodel= load_model('path/to/model.h5')
```

to confirm it loads, you can write: `model.summary`

From here you can change hyperparameters such as loss, learning rate, and you can even change or add layers.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) is the keras guide for saving and loading models.
I recommend using `ModelCheckpointCallback` to save every epoch so you can always go back if overfitting occurs

Answer (score 0):

You can start where you finished by using keras checkpoint.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy')

# Training 
nn_history = my_model.fit(train_ds, callbacks=[mc], validation_data=validation_ds)

my_model = load_model('best_model.h5')
nn_history = my_model.fit(train_ds, callbacks=[mc], validation_data=validation_ds)
```